# How do I Insert table data into an html page?

Tags: php, html

I'm very new to php and just trying to learn but can't seem to get out of the gates, so please...no laughing:). I'm trying to create a very basic form that will alow me to grab info from mysql and post the info into an html page. Here's what I've got so far:

```
<?PHP
//connect to the server
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")

///connect to the database
mysql_select_db("test")

//query the database
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mary WHERE name = 'mary' ")

//fetch the results / convert the results into an array

WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query):

$name = $rows['name'];
$pet = $rows['pet'];
$email = $rows['email'];

echo "$name<br>$pet<br>;$email";
endwhile

?>

<html>
[name] had a little [pet]. Her fleece was white as snow. Everywhere [name] went, the [pet] was sure to follow.
</html>
```

I keep getting an error that looks like this:

Parse error: parse error in D:\wamp\www\test\modules\mod_php\mod_php.php(36) : eval()'d code on line 8

OR (if I don't ask for php evaluation)

```
$pet
;$email"; endwhile ?> [name] had a little [pet]. Her fleece was white as snow. Everywhere [name] went, the [pet] was sure to follow.
```

The php module file I'm working with is follows:

```
<?php
/*
* mod_html allows inclusion of HTML/JS/CSS and now PHP, in Joomla/Mambo Modules
* @copyright (c) Copyright: Fiji Web Design, www.fijiwebdesign.com.
* @author gabe@fijiwebdesign.com 
* @date June 17, 2008
* @package Joomla1.5
*/

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// mod_php version
$ver = '1.0.0.Alpha1-J1.5';

// get module parameters
$php = $params->get( 'php' );
$eval_php = $params->get( 'eval_php' );
$discovery = $params->get( 'discovery' );

// remove annoying <br /> tags from module parameter
$php = str_replace('<br />', '', $php);

// show that site uses mod_php
$debug = $discovery ? JRequest::getVar('debug') : false;
if ($discovery) {
echo "\r\n<!-- /mod_php version $ver (c) www.fijiwebdesign.com -->\r\n";
}
if ($debug == 'mod_php') {
echo '<div style="border:1px solid red;padding:6px;">';
echo '<div style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">Mod PHP</div>';
}

// evaluate the PHP code
if ($eval_php) {
eval("\r\n?>\r\n ".$php."\r\n<?php\r\n");
} else {
echo $php;
}

// end show site uses mod_php
if ($debug == 'mod_php') {
echo '</div>';
}
if ($discovery) {
echo "\r\n<!-- mod_php version $ver/ -->\r\n";
}

?>
```

Can anyone help a newbie from committing harikari? Thanks!!!

Comment: So, this is going into a Joomla-based website, or is it supposed to be just your standard webpage?

Comment: are you missing a ) after the `WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query):`?

Comment: If you don't do "php evaluation" you just get the raw contents of the file. There is no such thing as a PHP script - there's only text files that happen to contain php code blocks. If you did a view-source in your browser you'd see the raw PHP+html code.

Comment: Yes this will be going on a joomla based site.

Comment: Tried the addition) with no luck

Comment: Soory for the confusion, he module I'm using in Joomla has an option to eval code.  When I view source it's the same as posted

Comment: If it helps, I'm just trying to replicate essentially like a mail merge in word.  User places data into a field and then grad that field data and insert into html document.

Answer (score 1):

I have uploaded the code at following link.

http://monalisawebstore.in/test.txt

Check out the result in screenshot:-

http://screencast.com/t/ZbDkc5DqMg

Please let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing ';' at the end of connection code lines and query. Please check and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Getting a bit closer, closed the </html> and now data shows but why doesn't it insert int the statement?  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your statement is outside of any PHP tags, and thus isn't getting evaluated.

From your last comment I guess you're getting some data to show on the page, but the [name] and [pet] fields are not getting replaced with actual values in the statement.

Please replace this...

```
<html>
[name] had a little [pet]. Her fleece was white as snow. Everywhere [name] went, the [pet] was sure to follow.
</html>
```

with this:

```
<html>
<?php echo "$name had a little $pet. Her fleece was white as snow. Everywhere $name went, the $pet was sure to follow."; ?>
</html>
```

Let me know how it goes. Enjoy learning PHP!